# How can I print certain rows from a CSV in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime

My problem is that I have a big dataframe with over 40000 Rows and now I want to select the rows from 2013-01-01 00:00:00 until 2013-31-12 00:00:00

```
print(df.loc[df['localhour'] == '2013-01-01 00:00:00'])
```

Thats my code now but I can not choose an intervall for printing out ... any ideas ?

Comment: You can use `datetime` object and compare the dates if they are lower or bigger than before. That means you can also compare them if they are within a specific time interval.

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? Feel free to accept one (tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set your index as `datetime` and then use `pd.DataFrame.loc` with string indexers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2013-01-01', '2014-03-01', '2011-10-01', '2013-05-01'],
                   'Var': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

res = df.set_index('Date').loc['2010-01-01':'2013-01-01']

print(res)

            Var
Date           
2013-01-01    1
2011-10-01    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a datetime object and then apply the condition:

```
print(df)

date
0   2013-01-01
1   2014-03-01
2   2011-10-01
3   2013-05-01

df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'].loc[(df['date']<='2013-12-31 00:00:00') & (df['date']>='2013-01-01 00:00:00')]
```

Output:

```
0   2013-01-01
3   2013-05-01
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I want to print the whole year from 2013-01-01 00:00 until 2013-31-12 00:00

Comment: This solution would take every date between that year. The example that I have shown happen to have only two dates in that year range.